# Flagging comments in mobile version of the site

Tags: support, feature-request, comment, flagging, mobile-web

When I was using the mobile version of the site, I did not find an option to flag comments.
Why flagging comments in the mobile version is not possible? Any particular reasons?

Comment: This feature request on [meta.se] seems similar: [Allow flagging comments on mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213709).

Comment: Please use the "full site" version on your mobile device. It has same experience as desktop version but the content is adapted to fit mobile screen. To enable this, go to the bottom of any stackexchange page and search for "full site" link and click on it. And yes this "full site" is exactly the "responsive design" mentioned by @TheAmplitwist.

Comment: @ Paramanand Singh Thanks! Your suggestion is very helpful.

Comment: Update: the mobile view has been completely removed as of [2 March 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609).

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that how to flag comments in mobile say. So first of all go at the end and you will a find a option of "full site". For refrence-

[image]

Just click on the full site button. Now you are in the laptop sized site mode. Now you can flag the comment.

## I want to now return to mobile site. How to do so:

Just go at the most bottom and on the left side and on the left side you will see the option "Mobile". Just click on that. For refrence-

[image]

Comment: This answer is outdated since the mobile view has been completely removed on [2 March 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609).